# Table View Controller Test Program

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have this objective C program and error printout:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController

@end

------


#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1; 
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 50; 
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Zeile nummer %i",indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}



@end
```

ErrorCode: 
2012-09-16 21:05:36.204 renetest2[1176:fb03] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableView.m:6061
2012-09-16 21:05:36.206 renetest2[1176:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x14b4022 0xeb4cd6 0x145ca48 0x9ae2cb 0xb1d28 0xb23ce 0x9dcbd 0xac6f1 0x55d21 0x14b5e42 0x1d85679 0x1d8f579 0x1d144f7 0x1d163f6 0x1da3160 0x15e84 0x16767 0x25183 0x25c38 0x19634 0x139eef5 0x1488195 0x13ecff2 0x13eb8da 0x13ead84 0x13eac9b 0x15c65 0x17626 0x1cad 0x1c15 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

Comment: Please explain your problem, whatever you've done to try to fix it, and ask a question. Don't just slap down your code and the crash log.

Comment: Please REMOVE ALL UNNECESSARY LINES from your code. Here is a suggested format for asking questions: 1) How you reproduce the error, 2) What you're expecting the code to do (output/behavior), and 3) What the code actually does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sample above, if the dequeued cell was nil, the cell is not created. The function cellForRowAtIndexPath would need to look like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Zeile nummer %i",indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand the error and look at the method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Instead of `// Configure the cell...` you should alloc/init your cell.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

`UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

This means that the line

`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

hasn't been able to dequeue a cell instance, so the method is returning `nil`.

You need to check if the `cell` is nil, and then create a new instance if it is with:

```
if (nil == cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

You'll then be able to configure the new `UITableViewCell` instance.